# How to Create YouTube Playlist with Google Script and Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

How do I make this google sheets script work to update an existing Youtube playlist.

```
function addVideoToYouTubePlaylist() {
  // Read the source videos from Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Add your own playlist Id here
  var playlistId = "PLAYLIST_ID_HERE";

  // iterate through all rows in the sheet
  for (var d=1,l=data.length; d
```

Comment: Have yout tried anything? Where do you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

This is what you are looking for:

```
function updateYTPlaylist() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const yt_video_ids = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat([1]);
  
  const playlistId = "PLAYLIST_ID_HERE";
  
  yt_video_ids.forEach( vid => 
                       
     YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: {
          kind: "youtube#video",
          videoId: vid
        }
      }
    }, "snippet"));

   Utilities.sleep(2000);                                                             
}
```

### Explanation:

I assume you have a list of youtube video ids in a sheet with name **Sheet1** in the range **A2:A** like that:

[image: explanation]

the aforementioned code will iterate over this list `yt_video_ids` and it will add every video id into the selected playlist, defined by `playlistId`.

### Resources:

From the google script editor you need to click on **Resources** => **Advanced Google Services** and then enable **YouTube Data API v3** (as of now this is the newest version).

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like I'm almost there.

It's giving me the following error:

    GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.insert failed with error: 
    Forbidden (line 11, file "Code")

LINE 11 is as follows:
    
    YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert({

Comment: Did you allow the permissions?

Comment: Yes, I enabled YouTube Data API v3

Comment: Service accounts do not work for YouTube Data API calls because service accounts require an associated YouTube channel, and you cannot associate new or existing channels with service accounts. If you use a service account to call the YouTube Data API, the API server returns an error with the error type set to unauthorized and the reason set to youtubeSignupRequired. Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: @Weso'lee thank you have to click on permission after you run the code but I believe that is not the issue.

Comment: That was it! I must have been using a service account. I switched to my own personal account and it worked. 

One other question:

How can I make this script remove the videos that were previously in this playlist and then add the new ones from my list?

Comment: Where would I put the "YouTube.PlaylistItems.remove(id)" in this script?

Comment: I marked this question as answered, Thanks so much.